# Function prints post meta data does not work

Tags: 500-internal-error

I modified this code from the Twenty Eleven theme but it doesn't work and I cant see why.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_post_meta_data' ) ) :
/**
 * This function prints post meta data.
 *
 * Adopted from Twenty Eleven
 */
function theme_post_meta_data() {
    printf( __( '%1$sPosted on %2$s by %3$s', 'theme' ),
        esc_attr( '<span class="posted">'),
        sprintf( '</span><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="timestamp" "%3$s">%4$s</span></a><span class="byline">',           
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_attr( get_the_date() ),
        ),
        esc_attr( sprintf('<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span></span>' ,
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'theme' ), get_the_author() ) ),
            get_the_author() , ),
        ),
    );
}
endif;
```

I get a HTTP Error 500.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please add a proper problem/error description.

Comment: @kaiser I get a HTTP error 500

Comment: Close voting as "too localized" - see answer.

Comment: Have you checked you error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this code.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_post_meta_data' ) ) :
/**
* This function prints post meta data.
*/
function theme_post_meta_data() {
printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on </span>%2$s<span class="%3$s"> by </span>%4$s', 'theme' ),
'meta-prep meta-prep-author posted', 
sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="timestamp">%3$s</span></a>',
    get_permalink(),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    get_the_date()
),
'byline',
sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
    get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
    sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'theme' ), get_the_author() ),
    get_the_author()
    )
);
}
endif;
```

Comment: What exactly is different?

Comment: @kaiser There are small things like removing the esc_url() and then including the span in the string so that the class can be moved with the text for languages where the order is not the same.

Comment: +1 for showing your solution. Not too common upon 1 rep users :)

Answer (score 0):

you spelled your function wrong. You have thme_post_meta_data() instead of theme_post_meta_data. Therefore, you function does not exist

Comment: I doesn't work even with that correction. I have corrected it in my question.